# Cloud Functions for Firebase interrupted before finishing execution

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Function is observing `proposals/{jobid}/{propid}`. When a new proposals is added, and `child("isinvitation")` is null, the function successfully writes new node to `proposals/sent`, then adds an increment to proposals child of jobs `jobs/${jobid}`.

The function is failing when a proposal is removed. `userRef.child(jobid).remove()` is not triggered also, decrease to proposal child of jobs `jobs/${jobid}` doesn't happen.

```
exports.CountProposals = functions.database.ref("/proposals/{jobid}/{propid}").onWrite((event) => {
    const jobid = event.params.jobid;
    const userId = event.params.propid;
    const isinvitation = event.data.child("isinvitation").val();
    if (!isinvitation) {
        const userRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/proposals/sent`);
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            userRef.child(jobid).set({
                timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            });
        } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
            userRef.child(jobid).remove();
        }
    }
    const collectionRef = admin.database().ref(`/jobs/${jobid}`);
                return collectionRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
                        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
                            const countRef = collectionRef.child("proposals");
                            countRef.transaction(current => {
                                            if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
                                                            return (current || 0) + 1;
                                            } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
                                                            return (current || 0) - 1;
                                            }
                            });
                        }
                });
});
```

> Console log don't show any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is trying to do several writes in several places.  Each one of those writes is going to generate a different promise that tracks its completion.  You should return a single promise that resolves when *all* of the work is done.  As it stand right now, you are only returning a single promise from `collectionRef.once('value').then()`, which isn't itself returning another promise that tracks the completion of the transaction.

Basically, you need to be careful with tracking all writes with promises, and typically you use Promise.all() to wait for all outstanding work.

Comment: I am handling null values for event.data.child("isinvitation").val(); It doesnt make sense to me using the previous value there.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your function is supposed to be doing.  You're mostly saying what it's *not* doing.   Also bear in mind that you need to return a promise from a function that does work, such as update the database.  Right now you're not using any of the promises that are returned from the updates (remove, transaction).

Comment: The function does two things, when  new data and isinvitation=false writes or removes data in database `users/${userId}/proposals/sent`, then increment or decrease the value proposals in `/jobs/${jobid}`

Comment: I changed my answer.  It looks like you need to take care to return a promise that tracks the completion of all your work.  Right now it's not doing that very thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

"Event handler that fires every time a Firebase Realtime Database write occurs." - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite

I personally would've expected this to get triggered on a remove operation as well, however, it may be similar to AngularFire, where a `write` operation is not considered a `remove` operation.

You might look at this and see how you could get it to work with your situation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#changed

**EDIT:** After trying some functions of my own they seem to trigger on removal for me. I will look into your code more.